# Is possible to set the values to below zero and to maximum value, JsonSchema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, weather, weather-api, json-schema-validator

I want to validate the temperature and chill factor with a value to below zero but I'm not sure if using minimum: -10, -20 is correct to use, for example.

Also the same goes for realistic maximum values for the temperature, chill factor, and wind speed.

Whats is correct to use?

Many thanks.

The JsonSchema is bellowed as follow:

```js
 "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "weather": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "windSpeed": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "minimum": 0.00
                    },
                    "cityName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "currentConditions": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [ "Cloud", "Snow", "Sun", "Hail", "Rain", "Sleet", "Heavy Rain"]
                    },
                    "temperature": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "minimum": 0.00
                    },
                    "windDirection": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": ["Northerly", "North easterly", "Easterly", "South easterly", "Southerly", "South westerly", "Westerly", "North westerly"]
                    },
                    "windChillFactor": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "minimum": 0.00
                    }

                },
                "required": ["cityId", "cityName", "currentConditions", "temperature", "windSpeed", "windDirection", "windChillFactor"]

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when uncertain about these kinds of things I'd suggest one of the following two approaches:

1. Consult [json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#range). There, only `multipleOf` is described as only allowing positive values, but for `minimum`/`maximum` any numeric value (including negatives) should be fine (even though the examples only use positive values for simplicity's sake).
2. Use online validators like [jsonschemavalidator.net](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/) to test your schema against sample data to see whether it fails or succeeds validation as you expect it to.

---

Additionally, your schema looks fine. You may wanna include the `cityId` in the `weather.items.properties` though (and not just in the `weather.items.required`) to also indicate its type.

Comment: I will include the cityid as well, a type is a number. Thank you for helping me to understand.